# Reverse order in TableView with months

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I have a problem that seems quite simple but I can't figure it out how to do it.
I have a simple table in which I want to show every month of the year. I did it like that:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 12
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell") as! MyCell

    let monthName = DateFormatter().monthSymbols[indexPath.row]
    cell.dateLabel.text = monthName

    return cell
}
```

Now the table starts with january on the top and so on but I want it just the other way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse the array like this

```
let monthName = DateFormatter().monthSymbols.reversed()[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Sometimes it's just that simple. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
let monthName = DateFormatter().monthSymbols.reversed()[indexPath.row]
```